# Update view's model or datatable for client updates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In a web page, when a user deletes rows from a datatable, should I be using the view's model or the datatable to do the data manipulation? (I'm learning MVC 4, and I'm not sure if accessing the model causes a hit to the server.)

Here's a quick example of what I'm trying to do. In my controller, I'm returning some Person objects:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    people.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Geddy", LastName = "Lee" });
    people.Add(new Person() { Id = 2, FirstName = "Alex", LastName = "Lifeson" });
    // more people here...

    return View(people);
}
```

This is how my view references people (first line in view):

```
@model List<MiscCommon.Entities.Person>
```

In my view, I'm using datatables to display. That part is working just fine.

[image: datatables views]

In my javascript function, I'm successfully able to pass the ID when the user hits delete (the x) on a row in the table. However, **I'm not sure if I should manipulate the datatable directly (as shown below), or if I should be modifying @model** then refreshing the datatable. Which way is considered correct? Or is there even another approach that I'm not aware of?

```
function RemovePerson(personIdToDelete) {
    var oTable = $('#tablePeople').dataTable();
    var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();
    var rowToDelete;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var idFromCurrentRow = oTable.fnGetData(i, 1);  // ID column
        if (idFromCurrentRow == personIdToDelete) {
            rowToDelete = i;
        }                
    }

    oTable.fnDeleteRow(rowToDelete);
}
```

Note: I'm using the model to populate the table in the first place:

```
@foreach (var person in Model) {
                @:$('#tablePeople').dataTable().fnAddData([@MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("'<a href=\"\", onclick=\"RemovePerson({0}); return false;\">x</a>'", @person.Id)), '@person.FirstName', '@person.LastName']);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@model` only exists server-side. Once the DOM is rendered and sent to the client, the @model is disposed. You need to contact the server again to let database know that record should be deleted. You have two options to do that:

**Option One**

Contact the server during your `RemovePerson` function in Javascript via AJAX.

**Option Two**

Post the entire page back to the server and parse the results. This would require your table being wrapped in a `form` and an input for each one of your rows.

I prefer to use option one and using the `jQuery.ajax()` method found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use a ViewModel which is the what you will pass to your view. so it becomes:

```
Database -> Model -> Controller -> ViewModel -> View
```

And then when the users updates or deletes a record:

```
View -> ViewModel -> Controller -> Model -> Database
```

In other words you will create a PeopleModel class that will include only the properties needed for the view.

Comment: So, when editing the list of people in my javascript, I should edit the `@model` (in the view) or the datatable? And when you say ViewModel, is that the same thing as `@model` in the view?